# R: math notation in data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

```
> df = data.frame(Parameters = c(expression(beta[1])))
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : 
  cannot coerce class ""expression"" to a data.frame
```

I'm trying to write math notation in a data.frame, but it seems that the two are not compatible. Is there a way around this?

I have also tried

```
> data.frame(Parameters = paste(expression(beta[1])))
  Parameters
1    beta[1]
```

How can I get [image] to show up?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? What is your actual goal?

Comment: You can store strings in a data frame

Comment: @Dason I'm trying to store the string $\beta_1$ into my data.frame. Instead of writing just "beta1" I want it as the actual mathematical notation, i.e. expression(beta[1])

Comment: So you're trying to use `?plotmath` syntax in a data.frame column? That's not really going to work; that only works when plotting. Not sure where exactly you want this to render. Is this for a plot of some kind?

Comment: I see. I just wanted to create data.frame that I will pass into xtable so the final result will be in LaTeX. Just wanted the mathematical notations to come out correctly instead of just "beta1", "hat_sigma" or something of that sort.

Comment: Perhaps you could just use Unicode for beta. For actual LaTex, perhaps you can use RMarkdown and LaTex for inserting the dataframe in a document with the symbols that you want. I don't think that you can directly display LaTex in a column of a dataframe in the R Console.

Comment: Perhaps you're after something like this: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2007-April/130864.html

Comment: Expanding on @John Coleman's suggestion of using unicode, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48877641/superscripts-in-r) provides examples of how to do this with data frames in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store the latex code for those symbols inside a dataframe then be able to generate correct latex code from `xtable`, you will need to override the sanitize function in `print.xtable` by feeding in a dummy function that returns the input exactly (See this question: [Using xtable with R and Latex, math mode in column names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14877305/using-xtable-with-r-and-latex-math-mode-in-column-names)):

```
df = data.frame(Parameter = c("$\\beta_{0}$", "$\\beta_{1}$", "$\\beta_{2}$"),
                Estimate = beta, row.names = 1)

print(xtable(t(df)), sanitize.text.function = function(x){x})
```

Latex Table:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rrrr}
  \hline
 & $\beta_{0}$ & $\beta_{1}$ & $\beta_{2}$ \\ 
  \hline
Estimate & 0.05 & 0.10 & 0.15 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Similar to `xtable`, `stargazer` has some cool options to generate nice looking tables in latex. One thing you can do is to change the variable names to math notation using the `covariate.labels` argument in `stargazer`:

```
library(stargazer)

beta = 1:3*0.05
df = data.frame(Parameter = c("beta0", "beta1", "beta2"),
                Estimate = beta, row.names = 1)

stargazer(t(df), covariate.labels = c(NA, "$\\beta_{0}$", "$\\beta_{1}$", "$\\beta_{2}$"),
          header = FALSE, summary = FALSE)
```

This outputs a latex table code:

```
\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
  \caption{} 
  \label{} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}} cccc} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 & $\beta_{0}$ & $\beta_{1}$ & $\beta_{2}$ \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
Estimate & $0.050$ & $0.100$ & $0.150$ \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

You can copy and paste the code [here](http://quicklatex.com/) to render the latex table.

[image]

Also note that the default for `type=` in `stargazer` is `"latex"`, which generates latex code, but you can also specify `type="text"` to generate a table in your console. This option, however, does not allow you to render the math symbols.

```
stargazer(t(df), covariate.labels = c(NA, "$\\beta_{0}$", "$\\beta_{1}$", "$\\beta_{2}$"),
          header = FALSE, summary = FALSE, type = "text")

# ==========================
#              0     1     2  
# --------------------------
# Estimate 0.050 0.100 0.150
# --------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option using my package:

```
library(huxtable)
dfr = data.frame(Parameter = c("$\\beta_{0}$", "$\\beta_{1}$", "$\\beta_{2}$"),
      Estimate = 'beta')
ht <- as_hux(dfr)
escape_contents(ht) <- FALSE
ht # will print as TeX within a markdown pdf_document
```

Answer (score -3):

I am not very sure what you are trying to do here. If you are trying to create a dataframe df with a column named "Parameter" with values taken from a vector within a list beta, then the below code will do the job.

```
df = data.frame(Parameters = beta[[1]]) 
# Assuming that the first object in beta is a vector that you want to set as "Paramters" column.
```

Please provide more information as to what these objects are if this is not what you were looking for.