# Superscripts in R

Tags: r, dataframe, superscript

I am trying to output a .xlsx file with a column name that has superscripted text.

for example like:

```
holdings=data.frame("x"=rep(12,4), "y"=rep(14, 4))
colnames(holdings)=c("Name","RankTM")
```

but with the "TM" superscripted.

Anyone able to help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest *not* doing that. Column names should be plain text but you may have a good reason for doing this.

Find the unicode for `TM` (2122) and escape it like so `\u\+###`. eg: `colnames(holdings) = c("Name","Rank\u2122")`

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you so much. This was a special case used for automation/linking the output .xls files to indesign, so needed the superscript.

Comment: Right that makes sense. Glad I could help