# How to avoid changes in the row names when I use xtable package?

Tags: r, latex, xtable

Let's say that I have the following information.

```
My_inf<-structure(c(0.00376, 0.00332, 0.00256, 0.00371, 0.00179, 0.00817, 
0.00817, 0.00746, 0.00959, 0.00533, 3.44713, 3.44713, 3.44713, 
3.44713, 3.44713, -3.44713, -3.44713, -3.44713, -3.44713, -3.44713, 
1.0005, 0.99994, 1.00172, 1.00108, 1.00147, -0.00941, -0.00833, 
-0.00816, -0.00956, -0.00468, 2.95108, 2.95429, 2.94188, 2.94577, 
2.94165), .Dim = c(5L, 7L), .Dimnames = list(c("NSW$^{+}$", "QLD$^{+}$", 
"SA$^{+}$", "TAS$^{+}$", "VIC$^{+}$"), c("Mean", "Median", "Max", 
"Min", "Std. Dev.", "Skewness", "Kurtosis")))
```

I want to use the `xtable` command for transform this data frame into a latex table. Using `xtable(My_inf)` but i get the following output.

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rrrrrrrr}
 \hline
& Mean & Median & Max & Min & Std. Dev. & Skewness & Kurtosis \\ 
 \hline
NSW\$\verb|^|\{+\} \$& 0.00 & 0.01 & 3.45 & -3.45 & 1.00 & -0.01 & 2.95 \\ 
QLD\$\verb|^|\{+\}\$ & 0.00 & 0.01 & 3.45 & -3.45 & 1.00 & -0.01 & 2.95 \\ 
 SA\$\verb|^|\{+\}\$ & 0.00 & 0.01 & 3.45 & -3.45 & 1.00 & -0.01 & 2.94 \\ 
TAS\$\verb|^|\{+\}\$ & 0.00 & 0.01 & 3.45 & -3.45 & 1.00 & -0.01 & 2.95 \\ 
VIC\$\verb|^|\{+\}\$ & 0.00 & 0.01 & 3.45 & -3.45 & 1.00 & -0.00 & 2.94 \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

As you can see the row names have changed according to `xtable` command. My desired output would be, for example:

```
NSW$^{+}$ & 0.00 & 0.01 & 3.45 & -3.45 & 1.00 & -0.01 & 2.95 \\
```

How can  I get my desired output? I should change the row names in the original data frame or maybe use another package for latex tables.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14877932/1968; you can use `sanitize.rownames.function = identity`. This needs to be passed to `print` rather than `xtable` directly.

Answer (score 1):

This is interesting, but every R package library generates a little another code.

## Stargazer

```
library(stargazer)
stargazer(My_inf, type = 'latex')

% Table created by stargazer v.5.2.2 by Marek Hlavac, Harvard University. E-mail: hlavac at fas.harvard.edu
% Date and time: Ср, ноя 03, 2021 - 20:42:52
\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
  \caption{} 
  \label{} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}} cccccccc} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 & Mean & Median & Max & Min & Std. Dev. & Skewness & Kurtosis \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
NSW\$$\hat{\mkern6mu}$\{+\}\$ & $0.004$ & $0.008$ & $3.447$ & $$-$3.447$ & $1.000$ & $$-$0.009$ & $2.951$ \\ 
QLD\$$\hat{\mkern6mu}$\{+\}\$ & $0.003$ & $0.008$ & $3.447$ & $$-$3.447$ & $1.000$ & $$-$0.008$ & $2.954$ \\ 
SA\$$\hat{\mkern6mu}$\{+\}\$ & $0.003$ & $0.007$ & $3.447$ & $$-$3.447$ & $1.002$ & $$-$0.008$ & $2.942$ \\ 
TAS\$$\hat{\mkern6mu}$\{+\}\$ & $0.004$ & $0.010$ & $3.447$ & $$-$3.447$ & $1.001$ & $$-$0.010$ & $2.946$ \\ 
VIC\$$\hat{\mkern6mu}$\{+\}\$ & $0.002$ & $0.005$ & $3.447$ & $$-$3.447$ & $1.001$ & $$-$0.005$ & $2.942$ \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

## kableExtra

```
library(kableExtra)
kable(My_inf, "latex") 

\begin{tabular}{l|r|r|r|r|r|r|r}
\hline
  & Mean & Median & Max & Min & Std. Dev. & Skewness & Kurtosis\\
\hline
NSW\$\textasciicircum{}\{+\}\$ & 0.00376 & 0.00817 & 3.44713 & -3.44713 & 1.00050 & -0.00941 & 2.95108\\
\hline
QLD\$\textasciicircum{}\{+\}\$ & 0.00332 & 0.00817 & 3.44713 & -3.44713 & 0.99994 & -0.00833 & 2.95429\\
\hline
SA\$\textasciicircum{}\{+\}\$ & 0.00256 & 0.00746 & 3.44713 & -3.44713 & 1.00172 & -0.00816 & 2.94188\\
\hline
TAS\$\textasciicircum{}\{+\}\$ & 0.00371 & 0.00959 & 3.44713 & -3.44713 & 1.00108 & -0.00956 & 2.94577\\
\hline
VIC\$\textasciicircum{}\{+\}\$ & 0.00179 & 0.00533 & 3.44713 & -3.44713 & 1.00147 & -0.00468 & 2.94165\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

But if you are discontented - you can parse an output LaTeX code and remove redundant symbols.

Comment: Note that you shouldn’t use ‘stargazer’, because [‘stargazer’ is an utterly atrocious package](https://www.reddit.com/r/rstats/comments/6o9v9h/whats_your_favorite_relatively_obscure_r_package/dkgw9q1/). Use ‘[modelsummary](https://cran.r-project.org/package=modelsummary)’ or ‘[texreg](https://cran.r-project.org/package=texreg)’ instead, or *literally anything else*.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Hm, I didn't know this information ;) I'll try to make a latex code with texreg, moment.

Comment: @KonradRudolph An addition. Texreg didn't work for this data: ```texreg(My_inf, single.row = TRUE)``` ```Error in extract(l[[i]], ...) :
Neither texreg nor broom supports models of class matrix.``` And modelsummary, this package uses ```kableExtra```